# How do I remove NaN values from a NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy, nan

How do I remove NaN values from a NumPy array?

```
[1, 2, NaN, 4, NaN, 8]   ⟶   [1, 2, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 592, accepted):

To remove NaN values from a NumPy array `x`:

```
x = x[~numpy.isnan(x)]
```

###### Explanation

The inner function `numpy.isnan` returns a boolean/logical array which has the value `True` everywhere that `x` is not-a-number. Since we want the opposite, we use the logical-not operator `~` to get an array with `True`s everywhere that `x` **is** a valid number.

Lastly, we use this logical array to index into the original array `x`, in order to retrieve just the non-NaN values.

Comment: Or `x = x[numpy.isfinite(x)]`

Comment: Or `x = x[~numpy.isnan(x)]`, which is equivalent to 
mutzmatron's original answer, but shorter. In case you want to keep your infinities around, know that `numpy.isfinite(numpy.inf) == False`, of course, but `~numpy.isnan(numpy.inf) == True`.

Comment: @dax-felizv I agree with @chbrown, NaN and Infinite are not the same in `numpy`. @chbrown - thanks for pointing out the shorthand for `logical_not`, though beware that it is considerably slower - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998188/how-can-i-obtain-the-element-wise-logical-not-of-a-pandas-series, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600988/python-tilde-unary-operator-as-negation-numpy-bool-array

Comment: Hmm, @mutzmatron -- I figured they did the same thing underneath the hood, and I'm getting very similar results with timeit (as did @unutbu at that first link): `python -m timeit -s "import numpy; bools = numpy.random.uniform(size=10000) >= 0.5" "numpy.logical_not(bools)"` vs. `python -m timeit -s "import numpy; bools = numpy.random.uniform(size=10000) >= 0.5" "~bools"` (`numpy.__version__ == '1.8.0'`)

Comment: @chbrown - you're right, any performance gain with numpy seems to have only occurred on the second posters machine - I tested `numpy.invert` and `numpy.logical_not` and got the same result for both as for `~`, on numpy v1.7.1. Not sure if architecture affects comparative performance - am testing on my chromebook (armv7l).

Comment: For people looking to solve this with an ndarray and maintain the dimensions, use [numpy where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html): `np.where(np.isfinite(x), x, 0)`

Comment: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: @towry: this is happening because your input, `x` is not a numpy array. If you want to use logical indexing, it must be an array - e.g. `x = np.array(x)`

Comment: Also, to completely remove the non-finite rows, use `.any(axis=1)`.
The full code will be 
`x=x[~pd.isnull(x).any(axis=1)]` for Pandas or
`x=x[~np.isnan(x).any(axis=1)]`for Numpy.
Note that these are working on different type of variables.

Comment: @Dark - thanks for the useful example for 2d data, though it's beyond the scope of the OP's question which relates only to a 1d input. Perhaps it would be useful for others posted as a separate Q and A?

Answer (score 76):

```
filter(lambda v: v==v, x)
```

works both for lists and numpy array
since v!=v only for NaN

Comment: A hack but an especially useful one in the case where you are filtering nans from an array of objects with mixed types, such as a strings and nans.

Comment: This might seem clever, but if obscures the logic and theoretically other objects (such as custom classes) can also have this property

Comment: Also useful because it only needs `x` to be specified once as opposed to solutions of the type `x[~numpy.isnan(x)]`. This is convenient when `x` is defined by a long expression and you don't want to clutter  the code by creating a temporary variable to store the result of this long expression.

Comment: It might be slow compere to  `x[~numpy.isnan(x)] `

Comment: Similarly, as a list comprehension, e.g. `[v for v in var if v == v]`

Comment: This can avoid `TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types` when the var contains mixtures of `nan` and strings, as noted by @AustinRichardson

Comment: what is v and what is x?

Answer (score 44):

For me the answer by @jmetz didn't work, however using pandas isnull() did.

```
x = x[~pd.isnull(x)]
```

Comment: or: `x = x[x.notnull()]`

Comment: I am not found of including pandas on the pipe but the accepted solution got me `TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types`. It does not work with strings or object types. This solution did.

Comment: Added benefit for this one is it removes `NaT`s out of the box

Answer (score 36):

Try this:

```
import math
print [value for value in x if not math.isnan(value)]
```

For more, read on [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: If you're using numpy both my answer and that by @lazy1 are almost an order of magnitude faster than the list comprehension - lazy1's solution is slightly faster (though technically will also not return any infinity values).

Comment: Don't forget the brackets :)
`print ([value for value in x if not math.isnan(value)])`

Comment: If you're using numpy like the top answer then you can use this list comprehension answer with the `np` package:

So returns your list without the nans: `[value for value in x if not np.isnan(value)]`

Answer (score 22):

[@jmetz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620982/3645374) is probably the one most people need; however it yields a one-dimensional array, e.g. making it unusable to remove entire rows or columns in matrices.

To do so, one should reduce the logical array to one dimension, then index the target array. For instance, the following will remove rows which have at least one NaN value:

```py
x = x[~numpy.isnan(x).any(axis=1)]
```

See more detail [here](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/numpy/python-numpy-exercise-91.php).

Answer (score 9):

As shown by others

```
x[~numpy.isnan(x)]
```

works. But it will throw an error if the numpy dtype is not a native data type, for example if it is object. In that case you can use pandas.

```
x[~pandas.isna(x)] or x[~pandas.isnull(x)]
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're using `numpy`

```
# first get the indices where the values are finite
ii = np.isfinite(x)

# second get the values
x = x[ii]
```

Answer (score 7):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620982/7128154) changes shape for 2d arrays.
I present a solution here, using the Pandas [dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) functionality.
It works for 1D and 2D arrays. In the 2D case you can choose weather to **drop the row or column** containing `np.nan`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def dropna(arr, *args, **kwarg):
    assert isinstance(arr, np.ndarray)
    dropped=pd.DataFrame(arr).dropna(*args, **kwarg).values
    if arr.ndim==1:
        dropped=dropped.flatten()
    return dropped

x = np.array([1400, 1500, 1600, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan ,1700])
y = np.array([[1400, 1500, 1600], [np.nan, 0, np.nan] ,[1700,1800,np.nan]] )


print('='*20+' 1D Case: ' +'='*20+'\nInput:\n',x,sep='')
print('\ndropna:\n',dropna(x),sep='')

print('\n\n'+'='*20+' 2D Case: ' +'='*20+'\nInput:\n',y,sep='')
print('\ndropna (rows):\n',dropna(y),sep='')
print('\ndropna (columns):\n',dropna(y,axis=1),sep='')

print('\n\n'+'='*20+' x[np.logical_not(np.isnan(x))] for 2D: ' +'='*20+'\nInput:\n',y,sep='')
print('\ndropna:\n',x[np.logical_not(np.isnan(x))],sep='')
```

**Result:**

```
==================== 1D Case: ====================
Input:
[1400. 1500. 1600.   nan   nan   nan 1700.]

dropna:
[1400. 1500. 1600. 1700.]


==================== 2D Case: ====================
Input:
[[1400. 1500. 1600.]
 [  nan    0.   nan]
 [1700. 1800.   nan]]

dropna (rows):
[[1400. 1500. 1600.]]

dropna (columns):
[[1500.]
 [   0.]
 [1800.]]


==================== x[np.logical_not(np.isnan(x))] for 2D: ====================
Input:
[[1400. 1500. 1600.]
 [  nan    0.   nan]
 [1700. 1800.   nan]]

dropna:
[1400. 1500. 1600. 1700.]
```

Answer (score 7):

In case it helps, for simple 1d arrays:

```py
x = np.array([np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 4])

x[~np.isnan(x)]
>>> array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
```

but if you wish to expand to matrices and preserve the shape:

```py
x = np.array([
    [np.nan, np.nan],
    [np.nan, 0],
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
])

x[~np.isnan(x).any(axis=1)]
>>> array([[1., 2.],
           [3., 4.]])
```

I encountered this issue when dealing with pandas `.shift()` functionality, and I wanted to avoid using `.apply(..., axis=1)` at all cost due to its inefficiency.

Answer (score 6):

Doing the above :

```
x = x[~numpy.isnan(x)]
```

or

```
x = x[numpy.logical_not(numpy.isnan(x))]
```

I found that resetting to the same variable (x) did not remove the actual nan values and had to use a different variable. Setting it to a different variable removed the nans.
e.g.

```
y = x[~numpy.isnan(x)]
```

Comment: This is strange; according to [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), boolean array indexing (which this is), is under **advanced indexing** which apparently "always returns a copy of the data", so you should be over-writing `x` with the new value (i.e. without the NaNs...). 
Can you provide any more info as to why this could be happening?

Answer (score 2):

Simply fill with

```
 x = numpy.array([
 [0.99929941, 0.84724713, -0.1500044],
 [-0.79709026, numpy.NaN, -0.4406645],
 [-0.3599013, -0.63565744, -0.70251352]])

x[numpy.isnan(x)] = .555

print(x)

# [[ 0.99929941  0.84724713 -0.1500044 ]
#  [-0.79709026  0.555      -0.4406645 ]
#  [-0.3599013  -0.63565744 -0.70251352]]
```

Answer (score 0):

pandas introduces an option to convert all data types to missing values.

- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html

The `np.isnan()` function is not compatible with all data types, e.g.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> values = [np.nan, "x", "y"]
>>> np.isnan(values)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

The `pd.isna()` and `pd.notna()` functions are compatible with many data types and pandas introduces a `pd.NA` value:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> values = pd.Series([np.nan, "x", "y"])
>>> values
0    NaN
1      x
2      y
dtype: object
>>> values.loc[pd.isna(values)]
0    NaN
dtype: object
>>> values.loc[pd.isna(values)] = pd.NA
>>> values.loc[pd.isna(values)]
0    <NA>
dtype: object
>>> values
0    <NA>
1       x
2       y
dtype: object

#
# using map with lambda, or a list comprehension
#

>>> values = [np.nan, "x", "y"]
>>> list(map(lambda x: pd.NA if pd.isna(x) else x, values))
[<NA>, 'x', 'y']
>>> [pd.NA if pd.isna(x) else x for x in values]
[<NA>, 'x', 'y']
```

Answer (score -2):

A simplest way is:

```
numpy.nan_to_num(x)
```

Documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html

Comment: Welcome to SO! The solution you propose does not answer the problem: your solution substitutes `NaN`s with a large number, while the OP asked to entirely remove the elements.