# python tilde unary operator as negation numpy bool array

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, multidimensional-array

Should be a simple question, but I'm unable to find an answer anywhere. The `~` operator in python is a documented as a bitwise inversion operator.  Fine. I have noticed seemingly schizophrenic behavior though, to wit:

```
~True -> -2
~1 -> -2
~False -> -1
~0 -> -1
~numpy.array([True,False],dtype=int) -> array([-2,-1])
~numpy.array([True,False],dtype=bool) -> array([False,True])
```

In the first 4 examples, I can see that python is implementing (as documented) `~x = -(x+1)`, with the input treated as an int *even if it's boolean*. Hence, for a scalar boolean, `~` is not treated as a logical negation. Not that the behavior is identical on a numpy array defined with boolean values by with an int type.

Why does `~` then work as a logical negation operator on a boolean array (Also notice: `~numpy.isfinite(numpy.inf) -> True`?)?

It is extremely annoying that I must use `not()` on a scalar, but `not()` won't work to negate an array. Then for an array, I must use `~`, but `~` won't work to negate a scalar...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`not` is implemented through the `__nonzero__` special method, which is required to return either `True` or `False`, so it can't give the required result.  Instead the `~` operator is used, which is implemented through the `__not__` special method.  For the same reason, `&` and `|` are used in place of `and` and `or`.

[PEP 335](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0335/) aimed to allow overloading of boolean operators but was rejected because of excessive overhead (it would e.g. complicate `if` statements).  [PEP 225](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0225/) suggests a general syntax for "elementwise" operators, which would provide a more general solution, but has been deferred.  It appears that the current situation, while awkward, is not painful enough to force change.

`np.isfinite` when called on a scalar returns a value of type `np.bool_`, not `bool`.  `np.bool_` is also the type you get when extracting a scalar value from an array of bool dtype.  If you use `np.True_` and `np.False_` in place of `True` and `False` you will get consistent behaviour under `~`.

Comment: Thanks ecatmur for the explanation, and especially for mentioning `&` and `|`.  I didn't know about those, and had used logical_and and logical_or instead.

Comment: I am using `numpy` for ages and till now did not know the purpose of those seemingly redefined-but-underlined constructs like `np.False_`. This all makes sense now