# Linear regression of arrays containing NANs in Python/Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math, scipy

I have two arrays, say `varx` and `vary`. Both contain NaN values at various positions. However, I would like to do a linear regression on both to show how much the two arrays correlate.
[This](http://glowingpython.blogspot.de/2012/03/linear-regression-with-numpy.html) was very helpful so far.

However, using the following

```py
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(varx, vary)
```

results in NaNs for every output variable. What is the most convenient way to take only valid values from both arrays as input to the linear regression? I heard about masking arrays, but am not sure how it works exactly.

Comment: Are the NaNs in the same or different positions in the two arrays?

Comment: At different/random positions throughout both arrays.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can remove NaNs using a mask:

```
mask = ~np.isnan(varx) & ~np.isnan(vary)
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(varx[mask], vary[mask])
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Didn't know the ~ operator means "is not".

Comment: @HyperCube careful with that, it only means "is not" for NumPy arrays (it's an abuse of the normal meaning, which is the bitwise not operator).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600988/python-tilde-unary-operator-as-negation-numpy-bool-array/13602395#13602395

Comment: To be fair, it's not that much of an abuse if masks are thought of in the old-school sense of bitmasks

Comment: You can also keep it positive using `mask = np.isfinite(varx) & np.isfinite(vary)`.  Of course this changes the meaning slightly to also exclude infinites.

Comment: @ecatmur, what happen if only vary contains some nan? when I tried to apply the method you suggest, i have the following error: ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: @user3841581 that would indicate that `varx` and `vary` are different sizes, even before removing nans.

Answer (score 1):

It's not relevant for `linregress` because it only admits 1-D arrays anyways but if `x` is 2-D and you're building a linear regression model using `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`/`statsmodels.api.OLS` etc., then it's necessary to drop NaNs row-wise.

```py
m = ~(np.isnan(x).any(axis=1) | np.isnan(y))
x_m, y_m = x[m], y[m]
```

In the above example, `any()` reduces the 2-D mask into a 1-D mask, which can be used to remove rows.

A working example may look like as follows.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
# sample data
x = np.random.default_rng(0).normal(size=(100,5))    # x is shape (100,5)
y = np.random.default_rng(0).normal(size=100)
# add some NaNs
x[[10,20], [1,3]] = np.nan
y[5] = np.nan


lr = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)             # <---- ValueError

m = ~(np.isnan(x).any(axis=1) | np.isnan(y))  
x_m, y_m = x[m], y[m]                         # remove NaNs
lr = LinearRegression().fit(x_m, y_m)         # <---- OK
```

With `statsmodels`, it's even easier because its models (e.g. `OLS`, `Logit`, `GLM` etc.) have a keyword argument `missing=` that can be used to drop NaNs under the hood.

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
model = sm.OLS(y, x, missing='drop').fit()
model.summary()
```