# Linear regression with Y values containing NAN using scipy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, linear-regression

I have two one dimension arrays and I would like to do some linear regression.
I used:

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
```

but the slope and intercept are always NAN, NAN. I read a little bit and I found  out that if either x or y has some NAN, that is the results expected. I tried this  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643363/linear-regression-of-arrays-containing-nans-in-python-numpy) but it doesnt work because, in my case, only the y contains some NANs; not x. So using that solution, I have the error: 
`ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly.`

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Can you interpolate your nans?

Comment: Can't you simply exclude nan values? I don't see what information they contribute to your model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mask the values in both `x` and `y` for which there is a `NaN` in `y`:

```
xm = np.ma.masked_array(x,mask=np.isnan(y)).compressed()
ym = np.ma.masked_array(y,mask=np.isnan(y)).compressed()

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(xm, ym)
```

Comment: (+1) are you interested in submitting this as an improvement to scipy documentation @tom? https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/629

Comment: sure, I'm happy to, but having never done so before, could you point me in the right direction please? :)

Comment: See, e.g., http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/hacking.html for a start. Let's move further discussion in the github issue I linked above.