# How to apply linear regression to every pixel in a large multi-dimensional array containing NaNs?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, python-xarray

I have a 1D array of independent variable values (`x_array`) that match the timesteps in a 3D numpy array of spatial data with multiple time-steps (`y_array`). My actual data is much larger: 300+ timesteps and up to 3000 * 3000 pixels:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress

# Independent variable: four time-steps of 1-dimensional data 
x_array = np.array([0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4])

# Dependent variable: four time-steps of 3x3 spatial data
y_array = np.array([[[-0.2,   -0.2,   -0.3],
                     [-0.3,   -0.2,   -0.3],
                     [-0.3,   -0.4,   -0.4]],

                    [[-0.2,   -0.2,   -0.4],
                     [-0.3,   np.nan, -0.3],
                     [-0.3,   -0.3,   -0.4]],

                    [[np.nan, np.nan, -0.3],
                     [-0.2,   -0.3,   -0.7],
                     [-0.3,   -0.3,   -0.3]],

                    [[-0.1,   -0.3,   np.nan],
                     [-0.2,   -0.3,   np.nan],
                     [-0.1,   np.nan, np.nan]]])
```

I want to compute a per-pixel linear regression and obtain R-squared, P-values, intercepts and slopes for each `xy` pixel in `y_array`, with values for each timestep in `x_array` as my independent variable.

I can reshape to get the data in a form to input it into `np.polyfit` which is vectorised and fast:

```
# Reshape so rows = number of time-steps and columns = pixels:
y_array_reshaped = y_array.reshape(len(y_array), -1)

# Do a first-degree polyfit
np.polyfit(x_array, y_array_reshaped, 1)
```

However, this ignores pixels that contain any `NaN` values (`np.polyfit` does not support `NaN` values), and does not calculate the statistics I require (R-squared, P-values, intercepts and slopes).

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643363/linear-regression-of-arrays-containing-nans-in-python-numpy) uses `scipy.stats import linregress` which does calculate the statistics I need, and suggests avoiding `NaN` issues by masking out these `NaN` values. However, this example is for two 1D arrays, and I can't work out how to apply a similar masking approach to my case where each column in `y_array_reshaped` will have a different set of `NaN` values.

**My question:** How can I calculate regression statistics for each pixel in a large multidimensional array (300 x 3000 x 3000) containing many `NaN` values in a reasonably fast, vectorised way?

**Desired result:** A 3 x 3 array of regression statistic values (e.g. R-squared) for each pixel in `y_array`, even if that pixel contains `NaN` values at some point in the time series

Comment: [This blogpost](https://hrishichandanpurkar.blogspot.com/2017/09/vectorized-functions-for-correlation.html) looks like it describes what you're looking for.

Comment: This is a great answer, and works ridiculously fast: several milliseconds for the example above. If you want to leave a slightly more detailed answer linking the blog post and explaining why it answers the question, I'd happily mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This blog post mentioned in the comments above contains an incredibly fast vectorized function for cross-correlation, covariance, and regression for multi-dimensional data in Python. It produces all of the regression outputs I need, and does so in milliseconds as it relies entirely on simple vectorised array operations in `xarray`.

https://hrishichandanpurkar.blogspot.com/2017/09/vectorized-functions-for-correlation.html

I have made one minor change (first line after `#3`) to ensure the function correctly accounts for different numbers of NaN values in each pixel:

```
def lag_linregress_3D(x, y, lagx=0, lagy=0):
"""
Input: Two xr.Datarrays of any dimensions with the first dim being time. 
Thus the input data could be a 1D time series, or for example, have three 
dimensions (time, lat, lon). 
Datasets can be provided in any order, but note that the regression slope 
and intercept will be calculated for y with respect to x.
Output: Covariance, correlation, regression slope and intercept, p-value, 
and standard error on regression between the two datasets along their 
aligned time dimension.  
Lag values can be assigned to either of the data, with lagx shifting x, and
lagy shifting y, with the specified lag amount. 
""" 
#1. Ensure that the data are properly alinged to each other. 
x, y = xr.align(x, y)

#2. Add lag information if any, and shift the data accordingly
if lagx != 0:

    # If x lags y by 1, x must be shifted 1 step backwards. 
    # But as the 'zero-th' value is nonexistant, xr assigns it as invalid 
    # (nan). Hence it needs to be dropped
    x   = x.shift(time=-lagx).dropna(dim='time')

    # Next important step is to re-align the two datasets so that y adjusts
    # to the changed coordinates of x
    x, y = xr.align(x, y)

if lagy!=0:
    y   = y.shift(time=-lagy).dropna(dim='time')
    x, y = xr.align(x, y)

#3. Compute data length, mean and standard deviation along time axis: 
n = y.notnull().sum(dim='time')
xmean = x.mean(axis=0)
ymean = y.mean(axis=0)
xstd  = x.std(axis=0)
ystd  = y.std(axis=0)

#4. Compute covariance along time axis
cov   =  np.sum((x - xmean) * (y - ymean), axis=0) / n

#5. Compute correlation along time axis
cor   = cov / (xstd * ystd)

#6. Compute regression slope and intercept:
slope     = cov / (xstd**2)
intercept = ymean - xmean * slope  

#7. Compute P-value and standard error
#Compute t-statistics
tstats = cor * np.sqrt(n-2) / np.sqrt(1 - cor**2)
stderr = slope / tstats

from scipy.stats import t
pval = t.sf(tstats, n-2) * 2
pval = xr.DataArray(pval, dims=cor.dims, coords=cor.coords)

return cov, cor, slope, intercept, pval, stderr
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer provided here https://hrishichandanpurkar.blogspot.com/2017/09/vectorized-functions-for-correlation.html is absolutely good in that it mostly utilises the great power of `numpy` vectorization and broadcasting but it assumes the data to be analysed are complete, which is not usually the case in real research cycle. One answer above intended to address the missing data problem but I personally think more codes needs to be updated simply because `np.mean()` will return nan if there is nan in the data. Fortunately, `numpy` has provided `nanmean()`, `nanstd()`, and so forth for us to use to calculate mean, standard error, and so forth by ignoring nans in the data. Meanwhile, the program in the original blog targets data formatted netCDF. Some might not know this but be more familiar with the raw `numpy.array` format. Therefore, I provide here a code example showing how to calculate co-variance, correlation coefficients, and so forth between two 3-D dimensional arrays (n-D dimensional is of the same logic). Note that I let `x_array` to be the indexes of the first dimension of `y_array` for convenience but `x_array` can surely be read from outside in real analysis.

#### Code

```
def linregress_3D(y_array):
    # y_array is a 3-D array formatted like (time,lon,lat)
    # The purpose of this function is to do linear regression using time series of data over each (lon,lat) grid box with consideration of ignoring np.nan
    # Construct x_array indicating time indexes of y_array, namely the independent variable.
    x_array=np.empty(y_array.shape)
    for i in range(y_array.shape[0]): x_array[i,:,:]=i+1 # This would be fine if time series is not too long. Or we can use i+yr (e.g. 2019).
    x_array[np.isnan(y_array)]=np.nan
    # Compute the number of non-nan over each (lon,lat) grid box.
    n=np.sum(~np.isnan(x_array),axis=0)
    # Compute mean and standard deviation of time series of x_array and y_array over each (lon,lat) grid box.
    x_mean=np.nanmean(x_array,axis=0)
    y_mean=np.nanmean(y_array,axis=0)
    x_std=np.nanstd(x_array,axis=0)
    y_std=np.nanstd(y_array,axis=0)
    # Compute co-variance between time series of x_array and y_array over each (lon,lat) grid box.
    cov=np.nansum((x_array-x_mean)*(y_array-y_mean),axis=0)/n
    # Compute correlation coefficients between time series of x_array and y_array over each (lon,lat) grid box.
    cor=cov/(x_std*y_std)
    # Compute slope between time series of x_array and y_array over each (lon,lat) grid box.
    slope=cov/(x_std**2)
    # Compute intercept between time series of x_array and y_array over each (lon,lat) grid box.
    intercept=y_mean-x_mean*slope
    # Compute tstats, stderr, and p_val between time series of x_array and y_array over each (lon,lat) grid box.
    tstats=cor*np.sqrt(n-2)/np.sqrt(1-cor**2)
    stderr=slope/tstats
    from scipy.stats import t
    p_val=t.sf(tstats,n-2)*2
    # Compute r_square and rmse between time series of x_array and y_array over each (lon,lat) grid box.
    # r_square also equals to cor**2 in 1-variable lineare regression analysis, which can be used for checking.
    r_square=np.nansum((slope*x_array+intercept-y_mean)**2,axis=0)/np.nansum((y_array-y_mean)**2,axis=0)
    rmse=np.sqrt(np.nansum((y_array-slope*x_array-intercept)**2,axis=0)/n)
    # Do further filteration if needed (e.g. We stipulate at least 3 data records are needed to do regression analysis) and return values
    n=n*1.0 # convert n from integer to float to enable later use of np.nan
    n[n<3]=np.nan
    slope[np.isnan(n)]=np.nan
    intercept[np.isnan(n)]=np.nan
    p_val[np.isnan(n)]=np.nan
    r_square[np.isnan(n)]=np.nan
    rmse[np.isnan(n)]=np.nan
    return n,slope,intercept,p_val,r_square,rmse
```

#### Sample output

I have used this program to test two 3-D arrays with 227x3601x6301 pixels and it completed the work within 20 minutes, each less than 10 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how this would scale up (perhaps you could use [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/)), but here is a pretty straightforward way to do this with a pandas `DataFrame` using the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress

# Independent variable: four time-steps of 1-dimensional data 
x_array = np.array([0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4])

# Dependent variable: four time-steps of 3x3 spatial data
y_array = np.array([[[-0.2,   -0.2,   -0.3],
                     [-0.3,   -0.2,   -0.3],
                     [-0.3,   -0.4,   -0.4]],

                    [[-0.2,   -0.2,   -0.4],
                     [-0.3,   np.nan, -0.3],
                     [-0.3,   -0.3,   -0.4]],

                    [[np.nan, np.nan, -0.3],
                     [-0.2,   -0.3,   -0.7],
                     [-0.3,   -0.3,   -0.3]],

                    [[-0.1,   -0.3,   np.nan],
                     [-0.2,   -0.3,   np.nan],
                     [-0.1,   np.nan, np.nan]]])

def lin_regress(col):
    "Mask nulls and apply stats.linregress"
    col = col.loc[~pd.isnull(col)]
    return linregress(col.index.tolist(), col)

# Build the DataFrame (each index represents a pixel)
df = pd.DataFrame(y_array.reshape(len(y_array), -1), index=x_array.tolist())

# Apply a our custom linregress wrapper to each function, split the tuple into separate columns
final_df = df.apply(lin_regress).apply(pd.Series)

# Name the index and columns to make this easier to read
final_df.columns, final_df.index.name = 'slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err'.split(', '), 'pixel_number'

print(final_df)
```

Output:

```
                 slope  intercept   r_value       p_value   std_err
pixel_number                                                       
0             0.071429  -0.192857  0.188982  8.789623e-01  0.371154
1            -0.071429  -0.207143 -0.188982  8.789623e-01  0.371154
2             0.357143  -0.464286  0.944911  2.122956e-01  0.123718
3             0.105263  -0.289474  0.229416  7.705843e-01  0.315789
4             1.000000  -0.700000  1.000000  9.003163e-11  0.000000
5            -0.285714  -0.328571 -0.188982  8.789623e-01  1.484615
6             0.105263  -0.289474  0.132453  8.675468e-01  0.557000
7            -0.285714  -0.228571 -0.755929  4.543711e-01  0.247436
8             0.071429  -0.392857  0.188982  8.789623e-01  0.371154
```

Answer (score 4):

At numpy level , you can use [np.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

First define the tricky part for each set of data :

```
def compute(x,y):
        mask=~np.isnan(y)
        return linregress(x[mask],y[mask])
```

Then define the function which will crunch your data:

```
comp = np.vectorize(compute,signature="(k),(k)->(),(),(),(),()")
```

Then apply, reorganizing data to follow broadcasting rules:

```
res = comp(x_array,rollaxis(y_array,0,3))
```

Finally,

```
final=np.dstack(res)
```

Now `final[i,j]` contains the five parameters returned by `linregress` for the pixel `(i,j)` .

It's roughly equivalent than the pandas method answer, but 2.5 X faster .
It takes about 5 seconds  for  a 300x(100x100 image) problem, so count an hour for yours.  I don't think it's easy to do better, since the time is essentially spent in the `linregress` function.