# Slope from linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a plot-

[image]

When I am trying to do linear regression on it-

```
df=pd.read_csv('tau.csv')


xx= df['xx'].tolist()
yy=df['yy'].tolist()
from scipy.stats import linregress
#print(linregress(xx,yy))

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err=linregress(xx,yy)
print(slope)

plt.plot(xx,yy,'ro')
plt.xlabel('log(l)')
plt.ylabel('log(Rl)')
plt.title('Fractal dimension with '+str(slope))
plt.show()
```

I get the slope as nan.

my data-

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear regression of arrays containing NANs in Python/Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643363/linear-regression-of-arrays-containing-nans-in-python-numpy)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have `nan` in your data:

```
x = [1,2, np.nan]
y = [2,4,6]

linregress(x,y)

>>> LinregressResult(slope=nan, intercept=nan, rvalue=nan, pvalue=nan, stderr=nan)
```

Also, you don't need to convert series to list, you can certainly do:

```
lingress(df['xx'], df['yy'])
```

Comment: This looks like the right explanation, although the docs for scipy 1.3 `linregress` appear to claim that missing data is handled "in pairs". Looking at the source of "linregress", I don't think that it is the case.