# Inverting a numpy boolean array using ~

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean-operations, negation

Can I use `~A` to invert a numpy array of booleans, instead of the rather awkward functions `np.logical_and()` and `np.invert()`?

Indeed, `~` seems to work fine, but I can't find it in any nympy reference manual, and - more alarmingly - it certainly does *not* work with scalars (e.g. `bool(~True)` returns `True` !), so I'm a little bit worried ...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600988/python-tilde-unary-operator-as-negation-numpy-bool-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python tilde unary operator as negation numpy bool array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600988/python-tilde-unary-operator-as-negation-numpy-bool-array)

Answer (score 76):

short answer: YES

Ref:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html

Notice:

> Computes the bit-wise NOT of the underlying binary representation of the integers in the input arrays. This ufunc implements the C/Python operator ~.

and

> bitwise_not is an alias for invert:

```
>> np.bitwise_not is np.invert
>> True
```

Comment: However, be careful that this will not work with an array of 0's and 1's! It will only work with an array of booleans. If you need to handle that kind of flexibility, use numpy.logical_not instead

Comment: @tvt173 Yes, `boolean not` and `logic not` are always different. Both the question and the answer are about `boolean not`. Thanks for reminding anyway.

Comment: Note that, this actually only works when the array's `dtype=bool`. I just stumbled upon the edge case of an array full of `True` and `False` objects with `dtype=object`. These are converted like `~True => -2` and `~False => -1`. See the duplicate target linked in the question comments.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the tilde if the array's `dtype` is boolean and you are sure that this won't change as the software matures. However, `np.logical_not` has two advantages:

- It also works for object arrays, which can easily show up if `np.nan`s or other objects make it into your array.
- Its meaning is clear to anyone with a little background in logics.

There is also `np.invert` but it doesn't work with object arrays and the word is ambiguous.

```
~np.array([False, True], dtype=bool)
Out[7]: array([ True, False])

~np.array([False, True], dtype=object)
Out[9]: array([-1, -2], dtype=object)

np.invert([True, False])
Out[4]: array([False,  True])

np.invert((np.array([True, False], dtype=object)))
Out[5]: array([-2, -1], dtype=object)

np.logical_not(np.array([False, True], dtype=bool))
Out[8]: array([ True, False])

np.logical_not(np.array([False, True], dtype=object))
Out[10]: array([True, False], dtype=object)
```