# Python large list (~150M lists inside with 4 string elements each) convertion speeding up

Tags: python, performance, list, large-data

Through this code I get very long performance (over 24h) working on large lists (~150M list elements inside, with 4 string elements each). I need to delete around 66M tuples from it:

```
def erase_random_elements(elements_list, iterable_random_numbers):
    for i in sorted(iterable_random_numbers, reverse = True):
        elements_list.pop(i)
    return elements_list
```

It seems I've got enough RAM for it, so I don't need to chunk the list. How can I do it faster?

Comment: what is `iterable_random_numbers`?

Comment: list or generator you can iterate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `list.pop(i)` as it takes [`O(N)`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list) time for each delete operation (the *Delete Item* on the linked page). Since you have enough memory you can create a new list:

```
def erase_random_elements(elements_list, iterable_random_numbers):
    s = set(iterable_random_numbers)
    elements_list[:] = [x for i, x in enumerate(elements_list) if i not in s]
    #return elements_list -> not required actually because we're updating the list in-place
```

Note that here I used `elements_list[:]` because in your original function you're updating the actual list instead of creating a new one and that means all the references to that list will be intact. But if that is not required then you can simple remove the `[:]`, un-comment the return line and assign the returned list from the function to a variable.

Answer (score 3):

[Ashwini has provided a sound solution for using lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25200592/3005188) but I'd also like to suggest using [`numpy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/index.html) instead of the builtin Python lists.

The example below using [array indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) (using another array for indexing) as well as [`~` inverting the array indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728708/inverting-a-numpy-boolean-array-using).

```
import numpy as np

N = 100000
a = 10*np.arange(N) # Generate your large array.
b = np.arange(0,N,2) # Generate some indexes to remove from the array.

a2 = a[~b] # Use ~b to remove all elements that correspond to the indexes within b
```

Comparing the two solutions (Ashwini's list comprehension and the numpy method above) using `%timeit` in IPython shows that using numpy is significantly (~100x) faster:

```
In [28]: %timeit a2 = a[~b]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 ms per loop
In [29]: %timeit a2 = [x for i, x in enumerate(a) if i not in b]
10 loops, best of 3: 170 ms per loop
```

Comment: I hope `b` is a set here(in LC version), but I am sure LC are still going to be slow compared to NumPy.

Comment: @Ashwini yeah I converted `a` to a list and `b` to a set to make sure it was a fair test :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the values are **not falsy** (tuples), then you can do

```
def erase_random_elements(elements_list, iterable_random_numbers):
    for i in iterable_random_numbers:
        elements_list[i] = None
    elements_list[:] = filter(None, elements_list)
```

Comment: On Python 3.4 I get the result that for a list of 100000, and 50000 indexes (every second), this is ~5 times faster than Ashwini's answer.