# Python numpy boolean array not whole columns and rows

Tags: python, numpy

I want to apply the **NOT** operation on whole **columns/rows** of a **boolean Numpy array**. Is this possible with Numpy?

```py
matrix = np.array([[False for i in range(3)] for j in range(2)])
# Initial
# [False, False, False]
# [False, False, False]

matrix[:,1].not() # Something like this
# After not operation on column 1
# [False, True, False]
# [False, True, False]
```

Comment: Google led me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728708/inverting-a-numpy-boolean-array-using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, see [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_not.html)

```
matrix[:, 1] = np.logical_not(matrix[:, 1])
```