# Python: Assign NaNs to Matrix Elements Given Statements for Three Other Matrices

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, nan

I have three 2D-matrices (A, B, D) and one 1D array (C). A contains mostly NaN values, but also a few non-NaN. I would like to assign NaNs to all elements in matrix D whiwh fulfill the following two statements:

(1) If an element in A[i,j] is NaN, then D[i,j] shall be NaN.  (2) If B[i,j] is outside of the range  (0.3 - C[j]) to (0.7 + C[j]), then D[i,j] shall be NaN.

It might shine through that I am fairly new to python, but I have tried to compose this seemingly simple piece of code for too long now and I haven't had much luck googling python documentations on the topic either and now I am running out of time. So I am trying my luck here, if somebody has an efficient solution. As I understand python, one wants to avoid loops when possible for efficiency, so if somebody knows an approach using python functions, that would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

The code below doesn't work, but perhaps at least it can illustrate my ambition if it wasn't clear above.

```
import numpy as np
# Create the fake matrices A, B, C, D
A = np.full((4,5), np.nan)
A[0,0] = 2
A[1,1] = 2
A[2,2] = 2
A[3,3] = 2
A[1,3] = 2
B = np.random.rand(4,5)
C = np.arange(0.0, 0.1, 0.02)
D = np.ones([4,5])

# First loop: meant to fulfill the first statement
for i in np.arange(4):
    for j in np.arange(5):
        D[i,j][np.isnan(A[i,j])] = np.nan

# Second loop: meant to fulfill the second statement
for i in np.arange(4):
    for j in np.arange(5):
        if B[i,j] < (0.3 - C[j]) or B[i,j] > (0.7 + C[j]):
            D[i,j] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some [technical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13602395/7207392) vectorized logical operations require the use of bitwise operators. Thus your conditions combined would be written:

```
>>> idx = np.isnan(A) | (B < 0.3 - C) | (B > 0.7 + C) 
>>> D[idx] = np.nan
>>> D
array([[ 1., nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan,  1., nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan,  1., nan]])
```

(B was)

```
>>> B
array([[0.5363705 , 0.20608309, 0.60937827, 0.94685545, 0.80861546],
       [0.1716229 , 0.89674041, 0.39352757, 0.84573667, 0.87769432],
       [0.97621636, 0.81509133, 0.3808146 , 0.84032838, 0.07871174],
       [0.11719543, 0.38021362, 0.76113843, 0.70157337, 0.66438894]])
```

Comment: Thank you for that elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

Just writing the conditions you mentioned in a vectorial form will be:

```
ind=(np.isnan(A)) + (B<0.3-C)*(B>0.7+C)
D[ind]=np.nan
```