# Comparing columns of dataframes and returning the difference

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes (about 37) and would like to compare the columns names of these dataframes so that I know all of them have the same columns and columns order. The dataframes are stored as a list of objects (e.g. tbl[0] is the first dataframe, tbl[1] is second and so on).

I wrote the following block of code that will take each column of my dataframes (tbl) and compare them with other dataframes' columns, if there is difference then the index of these dataframes is appended to a 2D list, which I can later recall to see where the columns mismatch.

```py
a = [[]]
for i in range(0,len(tbl)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(tbl)):
        if(~(tbl[i].columns.equals(tbl[j].columns))):
            a.append([i, j])
```

But when I run the above code, it appends all the dataframes indexes that I am comparing. Is there anything wrong that I am doing here?

Example:

```py
tbl = []

for i in range(0,3):
    tbl.append(pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,4,5], 'c':[7,8,3], 'd':[1,5,3]}))

a = [[]]
for i in range(0,len(tbl)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(tbl)):
        if(~(tbl[i].columns.equals(tbl[j].columns))):
            a.append([i, j])
```

For the sake of this question, I have created 3 dummy dataframes that have same columns names (a, b, c, d). When I compare the columns names using the code mentioned earlier, I get the following output:

```
[[], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Shouldn't I be getting an empty list? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you add some sample data like `df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abc'))` with expected output?

Comment: Can you cross-check your first two dataframe's columns? are they really different?

Comment: Provide at least three dataframes and the expected solution. Please.

Comment: Added example now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if not` for working with [bool scalars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13600988):

```
print (~True)
-2

a = [[]]
for i in range(0,len(tbl)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(tbl)):
        if not (tbl[i].columns.equals(tbl[j].columns)):
            a.append([i, j])

print (a)
[[]]
```