# Extension of Comparing columns of dataframes and returning the difference

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

This is an extension of my previous question at: [Comparing columns of dataframes and returning the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55452462/comparing-columns-of-dataframes-and-returning-the-difference/55453400#55453400).

After comparing the columns of all the dataframes in my collection of 37 dataframes, i found that some of the dataframes have similar columns while some have different. So there is now a need to compare these different dataframes and return the difference. This step should continue until all the dataframes have been sorted into two groups, i.e., dataframes with similar columns into one group and different columns dataframes into second group.

for example:

```py
df = [None] * 6

df[0] = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,4,5], 'c':[7,8,3], 'd':[1,5,3]})
df[1] = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,4,5], 'c':[7,8,3], 'd':[1,5,3]})
df[2] = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,4,5], 'x':[7,8,3], 'y':[1,5,3]})
df[3] = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,4,5], 'c':[7,8,3], 'd':[1,5,3]})
df[4] = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,4,5], 'x':[7,8,3], 'z':[1,5,3]})
df[5] = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,4,5], 'x':[7,8,3], 'y':[1,5,3]})

# code to group the dataframes into similar and different cols groups

nsame = []
same = []
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
            if not (df[i].columns.equals(df[j].columns)):
                nsame.append(j)
            else:
                same.append(i)
```

When I print the above code for same group (same), the output is as:

```
print(same)
[0, 0, 1, 2]
```

Desired output:

```
print(same)
[0, 1, 3]
```

Perhaps I need a recursive function to group all similar columns into one group and all different columns dataframes into a different group. However, the tricky part is that there can more than two groups. For example, in the above code, there are 3 groups:

```
Group1: df[0], df[1], df[3]
Group2: df[2], df[5]
Group3: df[4]
```

Can someone help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```
s=pd.Series([','.join(x) for x in df])
s.groupby(s).groups # the out put here already make the dfs into groups 
Out[695]: 
{'a,b,c,d': Int64Index([0, 1, 3], dtype='int64'),
 'a,b,x,y': Int64Index([2, 5], dtype='int64'),
 'a,b,x,z': Int64Index([4], dtype='int64')}
```

---

```
[y.index.tolist() for x , y in s.groupby(s)]
Out[699]: [[0, 1, 3], [2, 5], [4]]
```

Comment: your answer works but since I have 37 dataframes and each dataframe has about 100-120 columns, I am thinking of a simpler output solution where I can just get the indexes as groups and not the columns names or dtypes. Is there any way to get this?

Comment: Edited your last code line with:

    pd.DataFrame([y.index.tolist() for x , y in s.groupby(s)]).T.fillna('').astype(int, errors='ignore')

and it works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier to pass all column names as a different pandas dataframe i.e.:

```
a - b - c - d
a - b - c - d
a - b - x - y
...
```

and just do a simple groupby over the columns

the count() series over groupby res will be the desired result