# Question about a array as another array index

Tags: python, numpy

I am confused about a operation of numpy, which using a matrix as index, like:

```
# a and b both are matrix:
a[b] = 0.0
```

The complete code are as following.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.mat('1 1; 1 2')

b = np.mat('0 0; 1 1')

print("a: ", a)
print("b: ", b)

a[~b] = 0.0

print("a: ", a)
```

And I get result are as following, but I don't know why.

```
a:  
[[1 1]
 [1 2]]
b:  
[[0 0]
 [1 1]]
a:  
[[0 0]
 [0 0]]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600988/python-tilde-unary-operator-as-negation-numpy-bool-array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396141/2d-array-indexing

Comment: @frederick-douglas-pearce, this is a weird indexing - see my answer.  I wonder if someone was really trying to do boolean array indexing and got this by mistake.

Comment: Is this something you found in some code example, or something that you stumbled upon by mistake?

Comment: I suspect the desired output was for boolean array indexing, maybe the author can clarify (sorry won't let me tag for some reason)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~` is not something we use much with numpy - so lets check that by itself:

```
In [184]: ~b
Out[184]: 
matrix([[-1, -1],
        [-2, -2]], dtype=int32)
```

Negative indices "count" from the end.

```
In [185]: a[~b]
Out[185]: 
matrix([[[1, 2],         
         [1, 2]],

        [[1, 1],         
         [1, 1]]])

In [186]: a[~b].shape
Out[186]: (2, 2, 2)
```

This result puzzles me, because `np.matrix` is supposed to restricted to 2d.

We are trying to discourage the use of `np.matrix`, but if I convert `a` and `b` to `ndarray`, the results are the same:

```
In [189]: a = np.mat('1 1; 1 2').A 
     ...: b = np.mat('0 0; 1 1').A

In [192]: a[~b]
Out[192]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 1]]])
```

indexing with an array, acts just on one dimension, here the first; so it's using a (2,2) array to index the first dimension of `a`, resulting in a (2,2,2).  This action would be clearer if the dimensions weren't all 2.

```
In [197]: a[~b, :]
Out[197]: 
array([[[1, 2],      # index is [-1,-1], the last row
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 1],      # index is [-2,-2], the 2nd to last row (first)
        [1, 1]]])
```

Since this indexing selects both rows, when used as a setter, both rows are set to 0.  So this is puzzling largely because `~b` produces a numeric index array.

I wonder if instead, this code was meant to do boolean array indexing.

```
In [203]: b.astype(bool)
Out[203]: 
array([[False, False],
       [ True,  True]])
```

Now `~` is a logical not:

```
In [204]: ~(b.astype(bool))
Out[204]: 
array([[ True,  True],
       [False, False]])
```

Indexing with a boolean that matches in shape, selects/or/not on an element by element basis:

```
In [205]: a[~(b.astype(bool))]
Out[205]: array([1, 1])

In [206]: a[(b.astype(bool))]
Out[206]: array([1, 2])
```

Now the the 0 assignment just sets the first row.

```
In [207]: a[~(b.astype(bool))]=0

In [208]: a
Out[208]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 2]])
```

The boolean array indexing would be clear with this example:

```
In [211]: b = np.array([[0,1],[1,0]], bool)
In [212]: b
Out[212]: 
array([[False,  True],
       [ True, False]])

In [213]: a = np.arange(1,5).reshape(2,2); a
Out[213]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [214]: a[b]             # select the opposite corners
Out[214]: array([2, 3])
In [215]: a[~b]            # select the diagonal
Out[215]: array([1, 4])
```

Comment: Yes, I think it is supposed to be boolean array indexing. I don't understand why the output `np.matrix` is 3d though, that seems like a bug to me. I know `np.matrix` is being deprecated but still concerning

Comment: Thanks for your help and the explanation is expected. And the type of b array actually is bool, and I mistake the true and number in python. Thus, it makes sense that the array can be the index of another array. The output dimension of the np.matrix is weird. I think whether there is a stack operation and I don't know.