# 2D Histogram out of array data set

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, heatmap

I have an array looking like this:

```
    array([[ 912.1,  821.5],
           [ 911.9,  821.5],
           [ 911.9,  821.5],
           ..., 
           [ 654.6,  552.8],
           [ 655. ,  553.3],
           [ 655.4,  553.7]])
```

So there are like 250,000 coordinates organized like that. Each contains one x-value and one y-value. 
I want to create a 2D histogram using this data. I've been looking at tutorials, but they all seem to show how to create 2D histograms from random data and not a numpy matrix like that. 
So in the end it should be a heatmap where red indicates more counts than blue for example.

Has anyone any ideas or hints to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: `pl.hist2d(data[:,0], data[:,1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply split the array into individual vectors for `x` and `y`:

```
x = arr[:,0]
y = arr[:,1]
```

Then, you can create a 2D histogram in the standard way using `hist2d`:

```
plt.hist2d(x, y)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Or, in one line:

```
plt.hist2d(arr[:,0], arr[:,1])
```

For further flexibility, e.g. changing the colorscale please read the documentation for [`numpy.histogram2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: I see I have a second problem. Some coordinates in this array are:

...
[nan, nan], 
[nan, nan],
... 

so there are no values. I want to leave them out or skip them.
If I don't do so I get this error:

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Is there a possibility to do so?

Comment: Please post a new question including an example. Or, even better, do a little research first. See e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11620914/2737715