# How to sum the values of a list's elements which elements' values come from anthor dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas DataFrame, which called `df1` and `df2`. I want to sum the list values in `df2` which the list's values come from `df1`.

For example:

df1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a',11],['b',13],['c',45],['d',88]],columns=['name1','data1'])
df1

    name1   data1
0      a       11
1      b       13
2      c       45
3      d       88
```

and df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a',['b','c','d']],['b',['a','c']]],columns=['name2','data2'])
df2

    name2         data2
0      a      [b, c, d]
1      b         [a, c]
```

Finally, I want this:

```
    name2   data2
0      a      146
1      b       56
```

How? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

First create dictionary by `df1` and then list comprehension with `get` for map value of `dict`, if values not matched is added `0` to `sum`:

```
d = df1.set_index('name1')['data1'].to_dict()
df2['data2'] = [sum(d.get(y, 0) for y in x) for x in df2['data2']]
print (df2)

  name2  data2
0     a    146
1     b     56
```

If want remove `NaN`s is possible use `filter` [with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29679784):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a',11],['b',13],['c',45],['d',np.nan]],columns=['name1','data1'])
print (df1)
  name1  data1
0     a   11.0
1     b   13.0
2     c   45.0
3     d    NaN

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a',['b','c','d']],['b',['a','c']]],columns=['name2','data2'])

d = df1.set_index('name1')['data1'].to_dict()
df2['data2'] = [sum(filter(lambda v: v==v, (d.get(y, 0) for y in x))) for x in df2['data2']]
print (df2)

  name2  data2
0     a   58.0
1     b   56.0
```

Comment: Great method. But what if `df2` value gets a Nan? It's zero.

Comment: @runningman - I think the best is remove `NaN`s rows with `d = df1.dropna(subset=['data1']).set_index('name1')['data1'].to_dict()`

Answer (score 2):

Can also do

```
d = dict(df1.values)
df2['s'] = df2.data2.transform(lambda v: pd.Series(v).map(d)).sum(1) 

0    146.0
1     56.0
dtype: float6
```

or

```
df2.data2.transform(lambda l: sum(d[i] for i in l))

0    146.0
1     56.0
dtype: float6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot` on `df1` to get names into columns, then index into `df2`:

```
pivoted = df1.pivot(columns="name1").data1.sum()
df2.data2 = df2.data2.apply(lambda x: pivoted[x].sum())

  name2  data2
0     a  146.0
1     b   56.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` with `dict.__getitem__`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int, df1.set_index('name1')['data1'].to_dict())

df2['sum'] = [sum(map(d.__getitem__, x)) for x in df2['data2']]

print(df2)

  name2      data2  sum
0     a  [b, c, d]  146
1     b  [a, c, e]   56
```

This will be more efficient than generator expressions for larger dataframes:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def jpp(df1, df2):
    d = defaultdict(int, df1.set_index('name1')['data1'].to_dict())
    return [sum(map(d.__getitem__, x)) for x in df2['data2']]

def jez(df1, df2):
    d = df1.set_index('name1')['data1'].to_dict()
    return [sum(d.get(y, 0) for y in x) for x in df2['data2']]

df2 = pd.concat([df2]*10000)

%timeit jpp(df1, df2)  # 32.8 ms per loop
%timeit jez(df1, df2)  # 49.1 ms per loop
```