# How to rise "{ValueError}Shape of passed values is ..., indices imply ..." during pandas read_csv() function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file:

```
a,b,c 
1,2,3
4,5,6
7
```

as you can see the last row doesn't match with count of headers. So I want to raise an `{ValueError}Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (3, 3)` error when I read the file with `pd.read_csv()` function

But if I do it in this way:
`pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])`
I get this error.

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using [remove NaN from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620914/removing-nan-values-from-an-array) you can try to create a new dataframe with NaNs filtered from `values` of dataframe from `read_csv()`

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""a,b,c 
1,2,3
4,5,6
7"""))#.astype("Int64")

try:
    pd.DataFrame(np.array([r[~np.isnan(r)] for r in df.values]), columns=df.columns)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

### output

```
Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (3, 3)
```