# How can I format a file to a multidimensional numpy array for my AI

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, formatting

I have a training set called `data.txt` stored for my AI.
The AI should get 5 `X` inputs each run and one solution/answer which is the array `y`.
The array `X` should look like following:
`[[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5],[x1,x2....x5],....]`
I tested it with 2 * 5 inputs and following came out:

```
    [2.21600000e+05 2.02000000e+03 2.43738600e+06 1.09990343e+01
 9.11552347e-01 2.21600000e+05 2.02000000e+03 2.43738600e+06
 1.09990343e+01 9.11552347e-01 1.00000000e+01 1.00000000e+00
 5.72000000e+02 5.72000000e+01 1.00000000e+01]
```

What I want is following:

```
[[221600,2020,2437386,10.999034296028881,0.9115523465703971],
 [10,1,572,57.2,10.0]]
```

The answer array `y` is fine. It is: `[0.,0.]`

The code:

```
import numpy
X=np.array([])
y=np.array([])
lineX=np.array([])
i=0
linenumber=0
with open('data.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        dataline=line.rstrip()
        dataline=float(dataline)
        i+=1
        linenumber+=1

        if i != 6:
            lineX=np.append(lineX,dataline)
        else:
            X=np.append(X,lineX,axis=0)
            i=0
            y=np.append(y,dataline)
print(X)
print(y)
```

And the file (the original has about 800 lines so I shortened it)

```
221600
2020
2437386
10.999034296028881
0.9115523465703971
0
10
1
572
57.2
10.0
0
```

The first five lines in the file are the inputs x1-x5 and the sixth line is y (the answers) and so on.

How can I get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will need two steps for this:

```
data = []
with open('data.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        dataline=line.rstrip()
        dataline=float(dataline)
        data.append(dataline)
data= np.array(data)
```

First we put everything in a numpy array. There are more efficient ways to read in the file i would assume i.e. pandas reading it as csv but for 800 values that shouldnt matter.

```
data = data.reshape(-1,6)
X = data[:,0:5]
y = data[:,5]
```

In the second step we split the array into full samples so columns 0-4 are you `X` values and column 5 is your `y` value

EDIT, Tangent on float values:

Integers are well definied in binary i.e. 1101 is 13. Floats have a problem though, you need to make a tradeoff between accuracy, as in decimal places, and min/max values so you dont have constant buffer overflows. So you have a fixed amount of bits responsible for your decimal places and another fixed amount for your exponent. You can read up on it [here](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-float/#:%7E:text=Python%20float%20uses%208%20bytes,a%20fixed%20number%20of%20bytes.).

This number in memory is always the same. What you are observing is the representation as a string when you print it. Numpy generally uses the scientific notation with is the same as `format(x,'1.8e')` for floats. If you want to print it in a different way use those format string to format it however you like for example you could use `format(x,'1.1f')` to give you the full number with a single decimal place.

Comment: note that in my case X is spelled uppercase

Comment: I don't understand why float makes numbers like 4.45500000e+03, are you sure it's working? It works without float but I need float numbers.

Comment: @france1 those are floats, its just a different output representation. There are some numpy flags you can set to force one kind or another but in memory this is a float.

Comment: They are too large. The code is running into buffer overflows. Something could be wrong with float(). If I run the code without the `dataline=float(dataline)` it works how I want except that the numbers are strings, so unusable for an AI. Isn't 4.45500000e+03 4.45500000^3? Why are those zeroes here?

Comment: I have to shorten those numbers. I'd like to have a maximum of 3 decimal places so I did following: dataline=round(dataline,3) 
Still huge numbers, it doesn't work.

`RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  error=(y_ -s)**2`

Once I fixed my problem with float() I can mark this question as the solution.

Comment: I don't understand it.  4.45500000e+03 should be 4455.0 so why is it doing it so complicated.

Comment: There are cases where s is nan or inf. s is the weighted x array.

Comment: @france1 i added an explanation on floats. Nan and infs in your data are a completely different problem to which you can find some info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620914/removing-nan-values-from-an-array

Comment: It turns out that the numbers are too large. There's a problem in the AI which - I tested - should work. I think the overflow causes the inf, -inf and endless nans afterwards. I can round the numbers but still have huge numbers. I rounded up to 3 decimal places and the numbers are crazy big in the X array but not in the data.txt. What might it be? I rounded -3 and the AI still gets this: `S is:  0.0
S is:  -8.776351721574362e+301
S is:  inf
S is:  nan
S is:  nan`

But no overflows

Comment: Oh the error message is on the beginning of the output, that's why I didn't see it.